# Protected properties of abstract class imported from external library not seen in extending class

Tags: typescript

I imported abstract class from external library

*abstract_guarantee_detail_view.d.ts*

```
export declare abstract class AbstractGuaranteeDetailView extends AbstractRequestState {
    ...
    protected transportAdapter: AbstractTransport;
    protected guaranteeId: string;

    protected isCreatedOrNew: boolean;
   
    constructor(transportAdapter: AbstractTransport, guaranteeId: string);
    abstract get canAddDocuments(): boolean;
    ...
```

I extended new class from this abstract class.

```
export class GuaranteeDetailView extends AbstractGuaranteeDetailView {
  constructor(protected transportAdapter: AbstractTransport, protected guaranteeId: string) {
    super(transportAdapter, guaranteeId);
  }

  get canAddDocuments(): boolean {
    return this.isCreatedOrNew;
  }
}
```

I want to implement abstract method `canAddDocuments` by using protected property `isCreatedOrNew` from abstract class. But **there is an error** `Property 'isCreatedOrNew' does not exist on type 'GuaranteeDetailView'.`
If abstract class is defined not in external library but in the same project then there is no such error. Construction `(this as AbstractGuaranteeView).isCreatedOrNew` saves the day but works only for public fields.
**What should I do?**

Comment: Hi, please share reproducable example

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your method to use "super":

```
  get canAddDocuments(): boolean {
    return super.isCreatedOrNew;
  }
```

Comment: that's really worked! but that was simplified example. in reality there are two classes - 1) BaseGuaranteeDetailView that extends AbstractGuaranteeDetailView ("super" works here perfectly) and 2) SpecificGuaranteeDetailView that extends BaseGuaranteeDetailView. How this second class can use properties of external abstract class?

Comment: You can add a getter in BaseGuaranteeDetailView which return "super.isCreatedOrNew". here it is already the case with canAddDocuments, so in SpecificGuaranteeDetailView you can access it via super.canAddDocuments